# Cron job creating empty files in root

Tags: command-line, root, cron

My cron job, command looks similar to this:

```
wget -q http://whatever-url/
```

It is running correctly (every minute). Problem is that it is creating empty php files at my root for every minute it runs. I'm not familiar with cron job commands. Is there a cron command that keeps this from happening, but will not alter the way script runs?

Comment: How did you add the new cron job and how exactly does it look?

Answer (score 4):

So tell `wget` not to output.

```
wget -qO /dev/null http://whatever-url/
```

Comment: The OP said: "*Problem is that **it is creating empty php** files*"

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yeah, I'm assuming a Wordpress behind-the-scenes script (per the URL that I've just edited out because it looked spammy) wouldn't need to output that much so that would leave an empty `.php` file. That's fairly common when you're writing a script that's only purpose is to be called from `cron`.

Comment: so basically i shouldn't set cron to run "all" (per minute) when i only want to run something once every 12 or 24 hours or so. i basically am just following the 'instructions' of the product.

Comment: @alx That's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying that if you're making requests to a file that you don't want to download, you should tell `wget` to not save the output. The default is to save and that's why you've got files popping up.

Comment: thanx for responding - oh okay, so the wget -qO will do that. (incidentally, that's an alpha "O" right? not zero) at first, the command line looks like it is just to disable completely. so it is to disable 'saving' of output. yes? sorry if i sound like a dufus, i don't know cron at all, i can draw with crayons and know a little html and php is about it for me.